# making robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I am making a robot.txt for my website. Can anybody cnmform that am i doing it correctly? If I am wrong, please tell me how to write in the correct form. 
*admincp*, *adminpp* etc are folder in my hosting server:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admincp/
Disallow: /adminpp/
Disallow: /Advertise with us/
Disallow: /ajax/
Disallow: /banner/
Disallow: /cont_img/
Disallow: /corcel/
Disallow: /css/
Disallow: /fbold/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /img/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /pic/
Disallow: /Scripts/
Disallow: /textpimg/
Disallow: /thumb_uploadtopics/
Disallow: /upload_p1/
Disallow: /uploadtopics/
```

Comment: If your website is tied to a Google Webmaster account, you can test your robots.txt file by going to Health -> Blocked URLs

Comment: rather than asking such questions on StackOverflow, first I advise you to do a little "googling", try it yourself, and if you face a problem, then come here. You'll find that you will be able to ask better questions, and people here will be more willing to help, you will get better answers, and I think these -ve scores on your questions will also turn into +ve.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can read this article to get a better grip on writing Robots.txt

http://seoroi.com/seo-faq/robotstxt-what-it-is-why-its-used-and-how-to-write-it/

For example, you can write:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /src/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /~zohaib/
Disallow: /temp/
```

Yes, you are doing it correctly it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If u r write correctly ur folder name and page name than u r right, not any problem i seen in your robots.txt file.

### Some instruction if u want to know.

user-agent : * --> means u r allow to all search engine bot for crawl.

Disallow : ---> means which one folder and page u don't want to allow to visitor.